# Exception Request method 'PUT' not supported

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a spring project with role based system. When i send put request to secured resource and have access denied exception i expected redirect to html page, but i have exception `org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'PUT' not supported`

My spring config, csrf disabled

```
 private void commonConfigure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    setupCsrfFilter(http);

    http.authorizeRequests().accessDecisionManager(accessDecisionManager())                
            .antMatchers("/**").hasAnyAuthority(ADMIN)
            .and().httpBasic()
            .and().jee().j2eePreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter(j2eePreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter())
            .mappableAuthorities(ADMIN)
            .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/unauthorized.html")
            .and().headers().contentTypeOptions()
            .and().xssProtection()
            .and().frameOptions()
            .and().httpStrictTransportSecurity()
            .and().contentSecurityPolicy(CONTENT_SECURITY_POLICY);
}
```

Comment: Do you have a `PUT` request mapping method in your controller?

Comment: Yes i have, if i sign in with admin role everything works fine

Comment: @Кирилл The question is: Can your /unauthorized.html handle a PUT request

Comment: /unauthorized.html it is static html page

Comment: is this a web app? or REST API? If web app which UI technology you are using thymeleaf?

Comment: Can you also share the PUT mapping and how you are trying to call it from web page?

Comment: @KuldeepSingh AFAIK you cannot handle a PUT request with a static HTML page. You have to use a controller.

Comment: @dur Yes. Better if he can share more details how the mappings are configured.

Comment: It is rest api, Ui - angular js, put mapping - simple rest controller.

Comment: @dur i thought if i add static page to accessDeniedPage method i should wrks fine and spring security resolve it

Comment: @Кирилл It is just a redirect. How could Spring Security know, what you like to do?

Comment: ok, i have to create controller with mapping /uanthrozed and return this page, then add this mapping to accessDeniedPage method?

Comment: @Кирилл Yes, give it a try.